# Does Ruby on Rails play nicely with the Google Code APIs?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, google-code

I'm interested in investing more time in Ruby on Rails and noticed how there isn't any specialized documenation for using Rails with the Google Code API:

http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide.html

Has anyone used Ruby on Rails with the Google Code API, and if so, were there any issues that might suggest looking into some other languages and frameworks (notably Python and Django)?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The API client libraries are written for *languages* (Java, Python, Ruby, etc.) not *frameworks* (Ruby on Rails, Django, CakePHP, etc.).

Google doesn't offer a Ruby API for Picasa Web Albums, so you'd either have to find an unofficial library or write your own.

Comment: It looks like a Ruby API (not necessarily for Picasa) is under development though.  Try visiting [gdata-ruby-client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-ruby-client/).  You get a 403.

Comment: yes, but those are just code samples.  They don't have anything to do with the 403 Forbidden link above.  Note that regular bad URLs on the Google Code project site give 404s.  That's a 403, which means it's restricted.